# How to change the command python3 to python in ubuntu terminal

Tags: python, linux

I have just started using Ubuntu. While using the VScode I have a few versions of python-interpretors listed since I have various python versions installed in my system, How to keep the latest version and remove the rest. Is it the reason that I am facing this issue, Would it solve the command `python3 manage.py shell` to `python manage.py shell`. How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: And BTW don't uninstall your default system Python. It will break your installation.

Comment: How to find out the default one and the others ? Yes, I know that Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add to `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias python="python3"
```

and restart the shell. This will only apply to your terminals and should not affect the rest of the system.

Alternative solution: add proper shebang line on top of `manage.py` (`#!/usr/bin/python3`), make it executable (`chmod +x manage.py`), run as:

```
./manage.py shell
```